# A question on a specific implication, given certain conditions

Tags: propositional-calculus

Is the implication
$$A \implies \left(B \oplus C\right)$$
logically equivalent to
$$\left(A \implies B\right) \oplus \left(A \implies C\right),$$
where $\oplus$ is the logical **XOR** operator, and $B$ and $C$ are *mutually exclusive* conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider the case where $A$ and $B$ are false, and $C$ is true. The first statement is true (since "false implies $X$" is always true), but the second is false (since both implications are true).